# Stripe webhook fails - Webhook error: 504

Tags: error-handling, next.js, timeout, stripe-payments

Stripe webhook fails and i assume its because Stripe doesnt recieve 'success' response from my webhook api endpoint.

Error is:

```
Test webhook error: 504

An error occurred with your deployment

FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT
```

I use Nextjs and its build in pages/api/createOrder folder structure to create a api. This is how my createOrder webhook looks like:

```
import { buffer } from "micro"
const AWS = require("aws-sdk")

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: process.env.MY_AWS_REGION,
  endpoint: process.env.MY_AWS_ENDPOINT,
})

// Establish Stripe connection
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)
const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_CREATE_ORDER_SIGNING_SECRET

const createOrder = async session => {
  console.log("create order - session.id: ", session.id)
  console.log(
    "create order - session.metadata.userID: ",
    session.metadata.userID
  )
  console.log(
    "create order - session.amount_total / 100: ",
    session.amount_total / 100
  )

  const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
  let date = new Date()

  // create Order
  let orderParams = {
    TableName: process.env.ORDER_TABLE_NAME,
    Item: {
      id: session.id,
      userID: session.metadata.userID,
      amount: session.amount_total / 100,
      adID: session.metadata.adID,

      createdAt: date.toISOString(),
      updatedAt: date.toISOString(),
    },
  }
  docClient.put(orderParams, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Order put err - " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
    } else {
      console.log("Order put Success - " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
    }
  })

  // create - TTL
  const ninetyDays = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 90
  const currTime = Date.now()
  const ttlSeconds = Math.ceil((ninetyDays + currTime) / 1000)

  // update Ad
  let adParams = {
    TableName: process.env.AD_TABLE_NAME,
    Key: { id: session.metadata.adID },
    UpdateExpression: "set paid = :paid, expdate = :expdate",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":paid": true,
      ":expdate": ttlSeconds,
    },
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW",
  }
  docClient.update(adParams, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("UPDATE Ad err - " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
    } else {
      console.log("UPDATE Ad Success - " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
    }
  })
}

export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const requestBuffer = await buffer(req)
    const payload = requestBuffer.toString()
    const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"]

    let event

    // Verify that the EVENT posted came from stripe
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, endpointSecret)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("ERROR", err.message)
      return res.status(400).send(`Webhook create Order error: ${err.message}`)
    }

    // Handle the checkout.session.completed event
    if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
      const session = event.data.object

      // Fulfill update Ad -> paid = true and ttl - expdate
      return createOrder(session)
        .then(() => res.status(200))
        .catch(err =>
          res.status(400).send(`Create Order Error - ${err.message}`)
        )
    }
  }

  // Notify Stripe that req reached api
  res.status(200).json({ received: true })
}

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
    externalResolver: true,
  },
}
```

I found few solutions how to tell Stripe that the webhook call was recieved but none of them worked. Right now im useing:

```
res.status(200).json({ received: true })
```

Maybe the problem is located somewhere else?
I want to note that Order is created and Ad is updated - so the webhook works as expected except that it fails.

Comment: The error message seems to be about the invocation of the webhook method. Are you sure these 2 lines will resolve to the request's body?

const requestBuffer = await buffer(req)
const payload = requestBuffer.toString()

Comment: Can you pin down the problem by adding logging to your code, trigger a webhook, see how far it gets based on what gets logged, then update your question with more specific details about where the failure is happening?

Answer (score 0):

In an event-driven architecture (webhooks), you usually want to return a 200 as fast as possible to the provider and then process the event after. This requires a queue to decouple.

You can check out https://hookdeck.com/. Their product seems to do exactly that (returning 200 to Stripe under 200ms) so you don't get Timeout errors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT` error is specific to Vercel, so is your app hosted there? Apparently the [timeouts](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview#general-limits) are quite low, and you could try increasing them.

---

Typically what you'd want to do when receiving a webhook is:

1. Store the webhook (e.g. in the database)
2. Send your HTTP response
3. Actually handle the webhook (e.g. in a background job)

This makes the response time faster and might solve your problem. It sounds like your `setTimeout` solution is kind of doing this — it's maybe sending the response before the handler is finished, which will be faster than putting it at the end of the handler.

Answer (score -1):

After 2 month of debugging i found a solution.

I think the problem was that AWS seems to be SLOW. I added setTimeout for notifying Stripe that connection was successfull and it now works!

```
setTimeout(() => {
    // 3. Notify Stripe that event recieved.
    res.json({ received: true })
}, 2000)
```

If some1 has better solution plz tell us :)

Comment: Once again i got proven that AWS DynamoDB is slow. For example i use react-query as server state maneger and there is a utility 'invalidateQueries() - 'refetches data after succesfull database update. But it fetches old data because the new data is not in the DynamoDB for like 100ms after successfull POST...